# CiviEvent rejects all online registrants for a free event

Tags: civievent

I have set up a free event (type "webinar") with online registration, but Civi automatically rejects anyone registering for the event. It is not related to waitlisting because the behaviour continues when I disable the relevant status categories. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to CiviCRM SE. Could you please provide some more details about 'rejects anyone registering for the event'?

If users are getting errors on the screen please can you add the error message to your question?

Check in CiviCRM config log to find if any error was recorded during user registration.

Check if the problem is specific to a single event or any event.

In case your system has a module/extension/plugin related to the Event, turn it off and check if the problem resolves.

If you have Civi-rules for Event, turn it off and check if the problem resolves.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Thank you! Users receive an on-screen confirmation of registration, but then receive an automatic email,
"Dear XXX
I am sorry to tell you that your registration for this event has been rejected. This is because you were not originally invited to this event.
Kind regards,"
The participant is recorded as "Rejected" and this cannot be changed without changing the participant type to "Invitee" and then changing the participant status manually. I will try those tips for checking what might be driving the behaviour.

Comment: I believe this is not Civi default behaviour, do you have any Civi rules set up for such condition and sending email?

Comment: Solved! I found a CiviRule over-riding participant status, which has been corrected.

Comment: Excellent!!! Could you mark the answer as resolved?